# Determining share of database limit used

Tags: azure-synapse

I understand how to alter the storage limit for an Azure SQL data warehouse per 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse

Is it possible to use SQL to determine the limit and the amount of space consumed of that limit so one could have an automated alert for "database near full" to avoid the consequences of an ADW database becoming full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the blade in the Azure portal for your Azure SQL DW, click the Monitoring tab, and click the second chart, you are taken to a Metric blade. Click the Add Alert button up top. Then you can define an alert on the `Total database size` metric. That alert could be set to email you when you surpass 15TB or whatever. There used to be a % full metric but I don't see that at the moment. So I think the alert will have to be hardcoded to a particular database size that you've calculated as 90% of the max database size seen on the Properties blade of your DW in the portal